# Editable List-view Item & Run-time calculation for each item on TextChange.

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask, android-edittext

I have a requirement but I don't know how to fulfill this. I have also searched on internet but didn't get close to this subject. The scenario is I have a ListView/RecyclerView. There is an edittext box & on this edittext based on quantity change I need to calculate the item price. There is also a field called special price but this will be a long running task and also will be calculated on quantity change. Any suggestion or hint will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: put your code here for better answer

Comment: I did not write any code till now but I assume when I will request for async task it will start calculate long time and retun value but I don't know which view or textview to update. As while user will scroll view might get destroyed. So before building this I want expert suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

you have a textview in your adapter
add textChangeListener to it and inside textChanged calculate total price
save calcualted value in a variable of your item class
and when bind viewHolder, display it inside total price
this did not take long time to respond
for example if you have a class to save shoppingList like this

```
public class shoppingList{
    private Integer id;
    private Integer count;
    private Double price;
    ...
}
```

add this variable to your class

```
private Double totalPrice;
```

tell me if need more description

Comment: i suggest you to write your code, then check its problems, you can determine real calculation time without writing none lines of code

Comment: Special price calculation will take huge time 100% in my scenario. I has a to loop through 5000 itms with custom logic. How ever you put usual solution. I am worry about when my data will return how I will get the item for which I was calculating because onScroll my item will get destroyed and also if i send event with textchange listner it will send multiple event so how to handle them also.

Comment: I will try to put some. Soon. Thanks.